# JQuery function for multiple button event with same Id

Tags: jquery, html, button, fadein

I am trying to call a JQuery function to occur fade in event for the buttons with same `id`, but it seems only first button in the brower can occur the event.

This is JQuery Function to "fade in" for buttons with `Id="skip"`. Once click the `button(Id="next")`, other `button(Id=skip)` is doing fade in.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button[id^="next"]').click(function () {
        $("#skip").hide().fadeIn(5000);
    });
});
```

This is the button `id="next"`

```
 <button id="next" type="submit" value="2" name="submit">Next</button>
```

And This is button `id="skip"`

```
<div id="skip">
<form method="post" >
<input type="hidden" id="skip_ig" name="skip_ig" value=""></input>
<div id="fade"><button type="submit" value="3" name="submit">Skip >></button></div>
<?php include('includes/aftersubmit.php');
</form>
</div>
```

I have multiple buttons of these "next" and "skip". But only first "skip" button does fade-in, others are not. Is Jquery function can only call first button when there are multiple button with same `id`? Thank you for your help.

Comment: "multiple button with same id". There is your problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is asked about a dozen times a day. The ID attribute must be unique within your document. You **cannot have multiple elements with the same ID**. This is undefined behaviour which typically manifests as only the first element being selected (presumably, at the browser level, subsequent duplicate IDs are ignored).

Comment: And Just in case there's any doubt, you cannot have multiple *anythings* with the same ID, not just buttons.

Comment: You are totally right. It works well. Appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 20):

You're using your attributes wrong. ID attributes should only be used **once** and should be unique. If you want multiple instances with the same identifier you should be using class attributes so instead of having

```
id="next"
```

you should have

```
class="next"
```

then just use the class selector as in

```
$(".next").click( function() {
    ...
});
```

and it should work for all of them

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this is what you want:

```
<button class="next" type="submit" value="2" name="submit">Next</button>
<div class="skip">
    <form method="post" >
        <input type="hidden" class="skip_ig" name="skip_ig" value=""></input>
        <div class="fade"><button type="submit" value="3" name="submit">Skip >></button> </div>
        Stuff here
    </form>
</div>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button[class^="next"]').click(function () {
        $(this).next($(".skip")).hide().fadeIn(5000);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tHcan/

Comment: I fixed it Exactly as you did. Thank you so much!